# Dynamically inserting Adsense unit

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, dynamically-generated

I am trying to dynamically insert an Adsense unit, but I don't get any clicks.

The ad is appearing just fine, since I changed to dynamically inserting the ad units (It was slowing down my HTML5 canvas) I don't get any clicks anymore.

This is the code I've used:

```
function appendAd(holder, client, slot, width, height) {
    window.google_ad_client = client;
    window.google_ad_slot = slot;
    window.google_ad_width = width;
    window.google_ad_height = height;

    var container = document.getElementById(holder);
    var w = document.write;
    document.write = function (content) {
        container.innerHTML = content;
        document.write = w;
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Maybe they kicked you out for breaking the TOS ?

Comment: @adeneo Changed it back to the original adsense unit code and I'd get clicks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Adsense support and they said it is not allowed.

Comment: hi, can you please point me to the doc that says it's not allowed? thanks